# How to extract characters in a string within a cell using in excel formula

Tags: string, vba, excel, text-extraction

Here is the sample string in A1 cell:

```
13TR@1X1127, 13TR@3X2500, @1X1373
```

I want to extract "n" in the pattern @nX, where n can be up to 3 digits in length, and then sum the value in Cell B1 .

Example:

```
13TR@1X1127, 13TR@3X2500, @1X1373

extract value: 1, 3, 1

And add in B1: 5
```

I have written the formula up to formula up to 2nd string but it seems it will be very long.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",A1,1)+1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,1))-FIND("@",A1,1)-1)+IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("@",A1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,1)))+1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,1))))-FIND("@",A1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,1)))-1),0)
```

Is there a way to simplify the formula so it will sum up to Nth String?

Comment: The pattern @nX where n is not a single digit, it may upto 3 digit. yes the string will separate by ",".

Comment: This is the formula I created upto 2nd string 
.=MID(A1,FIND("@",A1,1)+1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,1))-FIND("@",A1,1)-1)+IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("@",A1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,1)))+1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,1))))-FIND("@",A1,FIND("X",A1,FIND("@",A1,1)))-1),0)

Comment: Yes, it may vary, Is there a way to simplify the formula up to Nth string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a VBA function like this:

<sub>(**Edited** to allow for multiple digits between `@` and `X`.)</sub>

```
Function SumNums(strIn As String) As Integer
    Dim p1 As Integer, p2 As Integer
    p1 = InStr(strIn, "@")
    Do While p1 > 0
        p2 = InStr(p1, strIn, "X") - 1
        SumNums = SumNums + Val(Mid(strIn, p1 + 1, p2 - p1))
        p1 = InStr(p1 + 1, strIn, "@")
    Loop
End Function
```

Also this way, the "number of occurrences" doesn't have to be decided in advance.

Comment: What if the number between @ and X is varying from 1 to 3 digit

Comment: you're welcome.  Feel free to vote-up the answer as well, if it was helpful :-)